# How to set top css using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set top css using javascript ?

i try to using this code, but not work

```
old_top = 90;
new_top = old_top - 30;
document.getElementById("box").style.top=new_top."px";
```

Comment: change `new_top."px";` to `new_top + "px";`

Comment: Maybe like this document.getElementById("box").style.top=new_top+"px";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're used to PHP ;)

With JS you have to use the '+' operator to concatenate strings

```
document.getElementById("box").style.top=new_top + "px";
```

Comment: Maybe a `style`-attribute must already exists, or you will become an error that `style` is `undefined`.

Comment: The style attribute should always exist if the object itself exists.. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: +1 Oh, ok, maybe i refer to a old internet-explorer.